# Dynamic label in React Native using reanimated

Tags: react-native, react-native-reanimated

I try to create custom slider in RN and I fail to create label, which would show value of slider inside thumb. I've seen solutions using TextInput with Animated.createAnimatedComponent, but in my case I think it is not viable option as TextInput blocks PanGestureHandler and it is not possible to move slider.

I would appreciate any advice.

```
import {StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import React from 'react';
import {GestureHandlerRootView, PanGestureHandler} from 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import Animated, {
    useSharedValue,
    useAnimatedStyle,
    useAnimatedGestureHandler,
    useAnimatedProps,
    runOnJS,
} from 'react-native-reanimated';
import {COLORS} from "../../theme/theme";


const Slider = ({sliderWidth, min, max, step, onValueChange}) => {
    const position = useSharedValue(1);
    const thumbDiameter = 40

    const gestureHandler = useAnimatedGestureHandler({
        onStart: (_, ctx) => {
            ctx.startX = position.value;
        },
        onActive: (e, ctx) => {
            if (ctx.startX + e.translationX > sliderWidth) {
                position.value = sliderWidth;
            } else if (ctx.startX + e.translationX < 0) {
                position.value = 0;
            } else {
                position.value = ctx.startX + e.translationX;
            }
        },
        onEnd: () => {
            const value = min + Math.floor(position.value / (sliderWidth / ((max - min) / step))) * step;
            runOnJS(onValueChange)({value});
        },
    });

    const animatedStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
        transform: [{translateX: position.value}],
    }));

    const sliderStyle = useAnimatedStyle(() => ({
        width: position.value,
    }));

    return (
        <GestureHandlerRootView>

                <View style={[styles.sliderContainer, {width: 180}]}>
                    
                    <View style={[styles.sliderBack, {width: sliderWidth}]}/>

                    <Animated.View style={[sliderStyle, styles.sliderFront]}/>

                    <PanGestureHandler onGestureEvent={gestureHandler}>
                        <Animated.View style={[animatedStyle, styles.thumb]}>

                            {/* LABEL */}

                        </Animated.View>
                    </PanGestureHandler>
                </View>

        </GestureHandlerRootView>
    );
};

export default RangeSlider;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    sliderContainer: {
        justifyContent: 'center',
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%'
    },
    sliderBack: {
        height: 8,
        backgroundColor: '#DFEAFB',
        borderRadius: 20,
    },
    sliderFront: {
        height: 8,
        backgroundColor: COLORS.primary,
        borderRadius: 20,
        position: 'absolute',
    },
    thumb: {
        left: -20,
        width: 40,
        height: 40,
        position: 'absolute',
        backgroundColor: 'white',
        borderColor: COLORS.primary,
        borderWidth: 4,
        borderRadius: 999,
    },
});
```

[i want to achieve similar effect with label inside slider thumb](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AXzG6.png)